# C# Array - Returning More Bytes Than Expected

Tags: c#, arrays, serial-port

I wrote a test method that involves writing/reading arrays for an RS232 serial communication app

```
    private void RS232TestCommand()
    {
        byte[] test = { 0xAA, 0xBB, 0xCC, 0xDD, 0xEE, 0xFF };

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {

            // Send test command
            comport.Write(test, 0, test.Length);
            LogOutgoing(LogMsgType.Outgoing, "Find Serial Command Sent" + "\n");

            // Read response and store in buffer
            int bytes = comport.BytesToRead;
            byte[] response = new byte[bytes];
            comport.Read(response, 0, response.Length);
            LogIncoming(LogMsgType.Incoming, ByteArrayToHexString(response) + "\n");
```

This log should ONLY read {AA, BB, CC, DD, EE, FF} however it also appears to include the "ComboByte[]" shown below.

```
            // Create 4 byte array to hold first 4 bytes
            var firstfour = new byte[4];
            Array.Copy(test,firstfour,firstfour.Length);

            // Convert i to a hex value
            byte iHex = (byte)i;
            byte[] iHexArray = { iHex };
            LogOutgoing(LogMsgType.Outgoing, "Short Address" + i.ToString() + "\n");

            // Combine iHex with firstfour to create a new byte[] 
            byte[] ComboByte = {iHex, firstfour[0], firstfour[1], firstfour[2], firstfour[3] };
            comport.Write(ComboByte, 0, ComboByte.Length);
        }
    }
```

The output is correct for i=0 (AA, BB, CC, DD, EE, FF) but for i=1+ the response looks like the "ComboByte" + "Response" ... or something like {82, AA, BB, CC, DD, E0, 01, AA, BB, CC, DD, EE, FF}.

How do I make sure I ONLY return the "Response" byte array?

Comment: I'm guessing the error is actually in `LogOutgoing`. Could you post the code for that?

Comment: @JonB My apologies ... I should have mentioned that LogOutgoing is tied to a separate window where I post what command has been sent. LogIncoming represents the window for data being read from the port. Thanks.

Comment: Can you please provide the type information of `comport`, so that we know what you're actually using?

Comment: You are writing bad code.  BytesToRead will always be 0 when you don't single-step with the debugger.  It takes time for the device to receive your command and send stuff back.   Looping is required to get the entire response.  Which does require you *knowing* when to stop looping.

Comment: `private SerialPort comport = new SerialPort();`

Comment: The output is something like `EO`? If that's the case, the data is not Hex.

Comment: @Nevets - From what you've posted, I don't see how you would get extra data in your response array. I'm wondering if the code that outputs this data is actually at fault. And also, Hans is exactly right. Your code will only work by luck. You'll be better off with the data received event.

Comment: @Thomas W Sorry about that ... it should have read as E0 ... just fixed it

Comment: @Jon B Thanks for your response. My only issue with the data received event is that I need a specific data received event for this test and a completely different read event for everything else. Forgive my question if it seems dumb...but can I have 2 data receive events?

Comment: You would have one event handler with a switch for the application state. Or you could unsubscribe the handler for the first state and then subscribe the handler for the second state.

Comment: Serial communication requires a good bit of design to work right. I think you've got a ways to go.

Comment: @JonB Thank you. This is my first time working with serial communication and I appreciate your (and everyone here's) help.